# Верстка stackoverflow, flex заменяется на inline-block

Tags: javascript, html, css

Заметила, что верстка [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) выполнена с помощью `flex`'ов

Пример меню в шапке:

```
.so-header .-main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в ie9 (и я так понимаю в других более старых версиях браузеров) `flex` заменяется на `inline-block` при чем стили встроенные, видимо js-ом.

Пример того же меню в шапке, но для ie 9:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

modernizer не вижу чтобы использовался.

**Вопрос:** Как можно такое реализовать с помощью js (задать для каких браузеров какие стили задавать), потому как практически всегда используется css для такого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ковыряние в исходниках подсказывает, что в данном случае всё довольно примитивненько и костыльненько

```
// https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.ru.js?v=b200a9ef1cb2, line 2 lol
"init": function() {
    // ...
    if (StackExchange.options.user.canSeeNewHeaderDesign) {
        var e = document.body.style;
        "justifyContent" in e || "WebkitJustifyContent" in e || $(".so-header *:visible").css({
            "display": "inline-block",
            "white-space": "nowrap",
            "vertical-align": "middle"
        }).not(".-logo, .-logo *, svg, .-badges *").css("width", "auto");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: эмм я не понял.Что делает это функция можете описать ?@andreymal

Comment: @Избытоксусликов выключает флексбоксовые стили, если у браузера нет поддержки флексбокса (`justify-content` это один из флекбоксовых css, в этом коде с помощью `in e` проверяется его наличие)

Comment: благодарю @andreymal

Answer (score 2):

Такое можно реализовать не только с помощью `js`, например `yandex` имеет сервис (`http://phd.yandex.net/detect`) что бы через него узнать какой браузер и вообще какой тип устройство используется, и после этого можешь сразу подключить другие стили, скрипты и шаблоны.

Вот пример кода в котором я сделал проверку на мобильные устройства, но можно сделать ту же самую проверку на те устройства которые вы хотите.

```
$_SESSION['is_mobile'] = false;

$query = http_build_query(
        array(
            'user-agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        )
);
// TODO chenge sesion to config
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http' =>
    array(
        'timeout' => 1 // 30 sec
    )
));
$res = file_get_contents('http://phd.yandex.net/detect' . '?' . $query, null, $ctx);
$s = $res;
$s = <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
{$s}
</root>
END; //уберите пробелы с начало этой строки кода скопируете код у вас

$xml = simplexml_load_string($s);
$error = $xml->{'yandex-mobile-info-error'};
//если тип устройства определить не удалось - возвращаем пусткю строку
$is_ipad = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$is_ipad = explode('iPad', $is_ipad);
$_SESSION['mobile'] = false;
if ($res && $error != 'Unknown user agent and wap profile' || count($is_ipad) == 2) {
    $_SESSION['mobile'] = true;        
}
else {
    $_SESSION['mobile'] = false;
    $_SESSION['is_mobile'] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как ответ дан, но покажу ещё один способ без JS. Итак, Flexbox работает начиная с IE 10, условные комментарии работают до IE9 включительно. После основного файла стилей подключаем стили c `float` и/или `inline-block`:
`<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie.css"><![endif]-->`