# Корректно ли использовать table-cell блоки без table и table-row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

К сожалению, погоня за небольшим процентом потенциальных покупателий, использующих IE9 и ниже пока не даёт возможность широкого использования флексбоксов, а без них такие простые вещи, как центрирование содержимого по вертикали - целая проблема. Для этой цели можно использовать `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`, но правильно ли технически применять `div-ы` и другие элементы со свойством `display: table-cell;` без родителей `table` и `table-row` только ради вертикального выравнивания?

Comment: а вы посмотрите на SO или ruSO , вёрстка на flex но если смотреть с "древних" браузеров то чудесно превращается в inline-block, а вот и кстати вопрос в кассу : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678638/33274

Comment: @Максим Ленский, посмотрел. Возьму на заметку такой метод (хотя нельзя сказать, что он был хорошо охарактеризован), но всё же давайте вернёмся к поставленному вопросу.

Comment: если по поставленному вопросу то лучше использовать с table-row , но можно и без , работает так же корректно

Comment: @Максим Ленский, я вот как раз и хочу узнать, почему "лучше". Есть какая-нибудь техническая причина?

Comment: хм...  ну смотри ... раз таблицы то есть колонка и ячейка , ячейка всегда находится в колонке , так и должно быть .. row - колонка cell ячейка колонки ну и собственно всё

Comment: Это всё верно, если мы используем table-свойства по назначению, т. е. для табличной вёрстки. Но, как я уже говорил, `table-cell` представляет собой интерес как альтернатива `flex-box` для старых браузеров из-за возможности вертикального выравнивания. Кстати, несмотря на то, что в шапке данного сайта для IE9 заданы стили `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;`, последний никакой роли не играет, а центрирование по вертикали осуществляется другими средствами, в том числе и свойством `line-height`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61529/discussion-between---and-gurebu-bokofu).